# Does a chip retain information in sleep mode?

Tags: attiny, sleep

I'm trying to write a long term timer function on an attiny85 and currently I'm using a counter. I'm experimenting using sleep mode as detailed [here](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?KX0). I'm wondering if the chip "retains" information in sleep mode. For instance if I increment a variable and then go into sleep mode, will that variable be changed when the chip wakes again?

Comment: Depends if you store data in non-volatile or volatile memory.  SRAM, DRAM, and RAM memory are volatile whereas ROM, EEPROM are non-volatile memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, RAM is preserved during sleep mode on AVR8s (including the ATTINYs). From the datasheet...

[image]

Interestingly, it is even persevered across resets, and seems to even be persevered for as long as the chip is even slightly, slightly powered...

https://wp.josh.com/2014/03/03/the-mystery-of-the-zombie-ram/

Comment: **Interestingly, it is even persevered across resets, and seems to even be persevered for as long as the chip is even slightly, slightly powered...** I would consider that normal and expected. It is very rare for there to be a guarantee that RAM will be 0 on startup. It normally is 0 but counting on that is a huge potential source of bugs. I've seen a system that worked perfectly unless you switched it on below -10C at which point the memory wasn't all 0 on power up and it crashed. A temperature related software bug, unusual but it can happen.

Comment: It's extremely bad code that does not initialize SRam and registers (stack pointers etc) after a Reset, so there should never be the type of issue that 'Zombie...' described.

Comment: @JackCreasey I'd say it depends on the application. When you are coding for a chip with 0.5k of program memory running for a decade on a CR2032, then I don't think is it "extremely bad code" to avoid wasting bytes and cycles and Jules in cases when it makes sense! Why initialize a stack pointer for a program that never makes call or enables interrupts? Why statically initialize a variable that is guaranteed to be written to before it is read the first time?

Comment: @bigjosh. Point taken, but I can't think of a situation where you don't have stack pointers unless you are doing very specialized assembly programming.

Comment: Lots of applications on the very tiny ATTINYs where this makes sense. C is no problem if you know what you are getting into- but you usually do want to replace the default C start-up code though.

Answer (score 0):

AVRs do preserve its state even during reset. This is the exact property I took advantage of in my first LED chaser project many years ago with an Attiny85. The only button was the reset button. The internal state was preserved, so I only needed to increment a counter if it wasn't initialized yet (after a power on) and the current LED animation was selected according to this counter.